# Changing input type on submit

Tags: php, html, forms, input

I have the following:
First input which needs to be switched from password to text on submit.

```
<input type="password" name="test" value="hidden123">
```

Second input which is the key to change the input field.

```
<input type="text" name="key">
```

Submit:

```
<input type="submit" name="grant" value="unlock">
```

And finally the PHP code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['grant'])){
$pass=$_POST['test'];
$key=$_POST['key'];
$unlock = "123";
if ( $key == $unlock ) {
//change this so the input field 'test' changes to text rather than password
echo "success";
} else {
echo "fail";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Please be more specific. You want to display HTML with your form and input types changed? What do you want to do before `echo "success";`?

Comment: Makes no sense. Why would you need to change the type on submit? What do you mean "key to change the field"?

Comment: are you using ajax? Else you never can change something on submit, you can only alter the next page, which is described by Harpartap

Answer (score 0):

Use This :-

```
if ( $key == $unlock ) {

echo "<input type='text' name="test" value='".$_POST['test']."' ">";


}  else {

echo "<input type='text' name="test" value='hidden123'>";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the type of the Input element to Text on Submit, You can use JQuery which will execute on Submit.

Add this code along with your **Success** message inside `If` condition.

```
echo "<script>$(document).ready(function(){
           $('input[name=\"test\"').attr('type','text');
    });</script>";
```

The `attr()` is used to retrieve or set an attribute of an element.
PS: Don't forget to include JQuery Library.